# Store closure which references other closure

Tags: closures, rust

I am trying to make a system of callbacks in which any callback can by enclosed in another callback to modify it's behavior before or after calling it. This code works:

```
type Closure = Box<Fn(&i32) -> i32>;

fn foo() {
    let add_closure = |closure: Closure| {
        let bar: Closure = Box::new(move |x| {
            println!("{}", x);
            closure(x)
        });
    };

    add_closure(Box::new(|&x| x + 2));
}

fn main() {
    foo()
}
```

But as soon as I add lifetime bounds to the closure, it doesnt:

```
type Closure<'a> = Box<Fn(&'a i32) -> i32>;

fn foo<'a>() {
    let add_closure = |closure: Closure<'a>| {
        let bar: Closure<'a> = Box::new(move |x| {
            println!("{}", x);
            closure(x)
        });
    };

    add_closure(Box::new(|&x| x + 2));
}

fn main() {
    foo()
}
```

I get this error:

```
./vec_closure.rs:5:32: 8:11 error: the type `[closure@./vec_closure.rs:5:41: 8:10 closure:Box<core::ops::Fn(&'a i32) -> i32 + 'static>]` does not fulfill the required lifetime [E0477]
./vec_closure.rs:5         let bar: Closure<'a> = Box::new(move |x| {
./vec_closure.rs:6             println!("{}", x);
./vec_closure.rs:7             closure(x)
./vec_closure.rs:8         });
note: type must outlive the static lifetime
error: aborting due to previous error
```

It seems like adding the lifetime bound is causing the `Box` to become `'static`, but I don't understand why this is or how to avoid it.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you need to know that `Box<T>` has an implicit lifetime in it; if you were to spell it out, it'd be `Box<T + 'static>`.  The reason for this is that a `Box` can live as long as you want it to, so the thing you store *inside* of it *also* needs to live as long as you might want.  Only types that have a `'static` lifetime qualify.  To put it another way, this prevents you from boxing something that is only *temporarily* valid (like a `&'a T` is only valid for `'a`).

So `Box<Fn(&'a i32) -> i32>` is actually `Box<(Fn(&'a i32) -> i32) + 'static>`.  But, this is a problem because of that `'a`.  You *might* believe that this is saying "the closure takes a pointer of *some* lifetime", but it doesn't.  It's saying the closure *as a whole* is parameterised on some lifetime, and as a consequence, is only valid *during* that lifetime.

To put it another way, instead of saying "this type is a closure which takes a pointer (which is valid for `'a`)", you're saying "this type (which is valid for `'a`) is a closure which takes a pointer (also valid for `'a`)".

This is incompatible with the implicit `'static` which is part of the `Box<T>` type, so it won't work.

What you *actually* want is to make it so that the closure is valid for any old lifetime, and that's it's just its *argument* that's constrained.  You do this by using [Higher-Rank Trait Bounds](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html), like so:

```
type Closure = Box<for<'a> Fn(&'a i32) -> i32>;
```

Now, instead of picking a specific lifetime for which the `Closure` type is valid, this is saying that the type *itself* is always valid, but that the type of the argument is constrained by some arbitrary lifetime.

At this point, you can replace `Closure<'a>` with `Closure`, and it works.

```rust
type Closure = Box<for<'a> Fn(&'a i32) -> i32>;

fn foo<'a>() {
    let add_closure = |closure: Closure| {
        let bar: Closure = Box::new(move |x| {
            println!("{}", x);
            closure(x)
        });
    };

    add_closure(Box::new(|&x| x + 2));
}

fn main() {
    foo()
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this if I do want to specify a particular lifetime on the closure's arguments? The way I am using this is that I have two arguments, one of which has the same lifetime as one of the arguments to the function which creates the closure, and the other which has a lifetime parameter which is the same as well.

Comment: @BenjaminLee I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: For example, `fn foo<'a>(x: &'a i32, closure: Closure<'a>) -> i32 { closure(x) }`. What I am trying to do is make sure that the closure's arguments have the same lifetime as one of the lifetime parameters to the function. Another problem I just ran into was using `type Closure = Box<for<'a> Fn(&'a i32, Foo<'a>)>` where `Foo` is a structure. It works but any closure that I actually define says it doesn't fit the type `Closure`.

Comment: @BenjaminLee But *why* does the closure need to have the same lifetime?  By parameterising the lifetime of the argument, they won't *need* to match any more.  Also, your description is really vague as to what you're actually trying to accomplish.  I think you should ask a new question with more details showing what you're trying to do.  Comments aren't the place to back-and-forth work out what it is you're trying to ask for.